# Removing default styling from HTML list elements

Tags: html, css

So I have some code that looks like:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li> ... </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This has indented itself. I have no styling to indent this. According to the computed styling there is no margin-left, yet everything is actually indented, I guess this is the default behaviour of nested ul elements?

Regardless, on every nested ul, I have a class that is called `comment-children` I need to say only 5 down can indent (so `.comment-children .comment-children .comment-children .comment-children .comment-children` done, great) but at a width of 640px, all nesting must be turned off.

The part I am having the trouble with is that the `ul` elements are nested by default http://jsfiddle.net/d7az0jv3/

**What do you want to do**

- Remove all default nesting and let me nest it my self via the class `comment-children`
- At 640px remove all nesting.

Comment: The `<li>` elements have no `margin` set, but the parent `<ul>` elements do have `padding-left`: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/d7az0jv3/3/).

Comment: The method you propose, applying the same class on a set of nested elements, is not a recommended method of applying CSS styling.

Comment: (@SeekingTruth Does the spurious deletion of the concern question mean you fixed it, or that my comment led you to understanding where concern definitions go, or...? It's better to post an answer than to remove information that might aid others.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is insufficient to demonstrate what you want to do involving the class `comment-children`, but generally, to remove the indentation on lists across browsers, you should implement the rules

```
ul, li { margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0; }
```

Here's an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7az0jv3/2/)

If you want to only nest elements up to a certain level, my recommendation would be to apply a class to the base `ul` that sets the indentation, and then add a rule that stops the indentation at a certain depth below that base class. Here is an updated version of your code with the nesting stopping at level 5.

HTML:

```
<ul class="comment">
    <li>level one</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>level two</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>level three</li>
```

(etc., up to level seven)

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
ul, li { /* reset the margin and padding */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.comment ul {
     /* 1 em margin for the UL elements under .comment */
    margin-left: 1em;
}
.comment ul ul ul ul ul {
     /* stop the nesting! */
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/d7az0jv3/4/)